# Catch WMS empty answers with OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, wms, openlayers, getmap

I was wondering if there is a way with OpenLayers 3 to catch problems with WMS layers, such as the service not answering, or not sending any images/tiles. So that in case of errors with a distant WMS layer (such as OSM WMS or anything), we can switch to another layer.

It is easy to do that by "testing" the WMS GetMap and analyzing an random answer (on a selected BBOX for instance), and analyzing the answer with PHP for instance. But is there a way with JavaScript / OpenLayers ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom `tileLoadFunction` to request images via XMLHttpRequest, instead of just setting the image src. The procedure is described in detail in this Stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914173/how-to-add-a-http-header-to-openlayers3-requests.

Once you get the XMLHttpRequest response (in the onload handler function), you can analyse the response, and perform whatever action you desire (fallback to a different data source, show an error message, etc.).